# WCF Azure App Service fails randomly with ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-web-app-service

I have this error happen sometimes with a WCF application  deployed to an Azure App Service. At the same time that this error happens, we also have successful requests; for example, in one minute we might have 30 requests, with 2 of them failing with this error, and 28 passing without any issues.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

```
Exception information:
    Exception type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
    Exception message: Thread was being aborted. (path\web.config line 81)

Inner exception information (level 1):
    Exception type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
    Exception message: Thread was being aborted.

Inner exception information (level 2):
    Exception type: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
    Exception message: Thread was being aborted.

Request information:
    Request URL: someService.svc/Compress
    Request path: someService.svc/Compress
    User host address: 23.101.165.181
    User: 
    Is authenticated: False
    Authentication Type: 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\webapp__707e

Thread information:
    Thread ID: 57
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\webapp__707e
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Security.Roles.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Line 81 in `web.config` is the `<add />` element in the following block:

```
  <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add applicationName="BMS.net" name="SqlProvider" type="Ayuda.CloudManager.Providers.CloudManagerSqlRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="gzipMessageEncoding" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.GZipMessageEncodingElement, GZipEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dd38b054e1e8815c" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RequestProcessorBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RequestProcessorBehavior" name="Agatha.ServiceLayer.WCF.WcfRequestProcessor">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpsTransport_BinaryMessageEncoding" contract="Agatha.Common.WCF.IWcfRequestProcessor" />
        <endpoint address="Compress" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpsTransport_BinaryMessageEncoding_Compress" contract="Agatha.Common.WCF.IWcfRequestProcessor" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="HttpsTransport_BinaryMessageEncoding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="262144" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxStringContentLength="262144" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="HttpsTransport_BinaryMessageEncoding_Compress">
          <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="binaryMessageEncoding">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="262144" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxStringContentLength="262144" />
          </gzipMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <location path="someService.svc">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Choose the higher pricing tier, then try again.

Comment: @Jason: Why do you believe that will resolve the OP’s problem? Are you suggesting this is due to a resource constraint?

Comment: Which `<add />` element is causing the problem? You have two different ones in your `web.config` (one for `<roleManager />` providers, another for `<bindingElementExtensions />`).